# R - Classification of data based on multiple condition passed, one of them being type date-time

Tags: r, classification

I am trying to classify my data based on various condition applied to it. One of the conditions being in date-time (m/d/y hh:mm). The classification should take place in day/night i.e. time 07:00/19:00 for daytime and 19:01/06:59 as night time and also based on the season i.e. m/d/y. Is it possible to create new variable which is classified based on multiple conditions such as numeric data - temperature, humidity, factors- "strong winds","moderate winds" and date-time.

this is the structure of my data.

```
$ T       : int  11 11 13 13 14 16 17 17 18 18 ...
$ P0      : num  700 699 700 699 699 ...
$ P       : num  764 763 763 763 762 ...
$ U       : int  54 58 47 47 41 36 34 37 34 34 ...
$ DD      : Factor w/ 18 levels "","Calm","Wind 
blowing from the east",..: 17 17 9 17 9 9 9 9 9 10 
...
$ Ff      : int  5 3 4 4 4 5 4 6 7 7 ...
$ ff10    : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 11 10 ...
$ WW      : Factor w/ 3 levels "","In the vicinity 
thunderstorm",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ W.W.    : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
$ c       : Factor w/ 245 levels "Broken clouds (60- 
90%) 1020 m",..: 32 154 86 86 151 154 216 124 86 86 
...
$ VV      : num  16 16 NA NA 16 16 16 16 16 16 ...
$ Td      : int  2 3 NA NA 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...
$ datetime: chr  "9/30/14 23:00" "9/30/14 22:00" 
"9/30/14 21:00" "9/30/14 20:00" ...
$ T_g_5   : num  12.8 13.4 14.1 14.9 16 17.2 18 19.1 
19.9 19.9 ...
$ T_g_20  : num  16.3 16.5 16.7 16.8 16.8 16.8 16.7 
16.3 16 15.4 ...
$ T_g_35  : num  17.3 17.2 17.3 17.3 17.3 17 17.2 17 
17 16.7 ...
$ T_g_50  : num  17.5 17.5 17.5 17.5 17.5 17.5 17.7 
17.7 17.7 17.7 ...
$ T_g_75  : num  18.6 18.6 18.6 18.6 18.8 18.9 18.9 
18.9 18.9 18.9 ...
$ s_m_5   : num  0.182 0.184 0.184 0.187 0.185 0.192 
0.193 0.19 0.193 0.195 ...
$ s_m_20  : num  0.209 0.205 0.207 0.206 0.202 0.201 
0.195 0.195 0.195 0.19 ...
$ s_m_35  : num  0.142 0.142 0.142 0.146 0.144 0.143 
0.146 0.146 0.146 0.146 ...
$ s_m_50  : num  0.149 0.149 0.151 0.146 0.149 0.146 
0.144 0.144 0.149 0.149 ...
$ s_m_75  : num  0.139 0.144 0.144 0.144 0.144 0.144 
0.144 0.142 0.142 0.142 ...
```

I tried to classify data using the folowing code.

```
DF$pest[DF$T <= 15 & DF$T > 10 & DF$U >=50 & DF$U < 
75 & DF$datetime >= "9/27/14 13:00" & DF$datetime < 
"9/27/14 16:00" ] <- "Threat"
```

the following above code gives "NA" in my column pest. is there any other way to classify the above data?. Thanks.

dput output

```
 > dput(smalldata)
structure(list(X.x = 1:4, T = c(11L, 11L, 13L, 13L), P0 = c(699.6, 
699.4, 699.6, 699.4), P = c(763.5, 763.3, 763, 762.8), U = c(54L, 
58L, 47L, 47L), DD = structure(c(17L, 17L, 9L, 17L), .Label = c("", 
"Calm", "Wind blowing from the east", "Wind blowing from the east-northeast", 
"Wind blowing from the east-southeast", "Wind blowing from the north", 
"Wind blowing from the north-east", "Wind blowing from the north-northeast", 
"Wind blowing from the north-northwest", "Wind blowing from the north-west", 
"Wind blowing from the south", "Wind blowing from the south-east", 
"Wind blowing from the south-southeast", "Wind blowing from the south-southwest", 
"Wind blowing from the south-west", "Wind blowing from the west", 
"Wind blowing from the west-northwest", "Wind blowing from the west-southwest"
), class = "factor"), Ff = c(5L, 3L, 4L, 4L), ff10 = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), WW = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "In the vicinity thunderstorm", "Thunderstorm"
), class = "factor"), W.W. = c(NA, NA, NA, NA), VV = c(16, 16, 
NA, NA), Td = c(2L, 3L, NA, NA), datetime = c("9/30/14 23:00", 
"9/30/14 22:00", "9/30/14 21:00", "9/30/14 20:00"), T_g_5 = c(12.8, 
13.4, 14.1, 14.9), T_g_20 = c(16.3, 16.5, 16.7, 16.8), T_g_35 = c(17.3, 
17.2, 17.3, 17.3), T_g_50 = c(17.5, 17.5, 17.5, 17.5), T_g_75 = c(18.6, 
18.6, 18.6, 18.6), s_m_5 = c(0.182, 0.184, 0.184, 0.187), s_m_20 = c(0.209, 
0.205, 0.207, 0.206), s_m_35 = c(0.142, 0.142, 0.142, 0.146), 
    s_m_50 = c(0.149, 0.149, 0.151, 0.146), s_m_75 = c(0.139, 
    0.144, 0.144, 0.144), X.y = c(NA, NA, NA, NA), pest = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_)), .Names = c("X.x", 
"T", "P0", "P", "U", "DD", "Ff", "ff10", "WW", "W.W.", "VV", 
"Td", "datetime", "T_g_5", "T_g_20", "T_g_35", "T_g_50", "T_g_75", 
"s_m_5", "s_m_20", "s_m_35", "s_m_50", "s_m_75", "X.y", "pest"
), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please edit your question to provide sample data in a copy&paste-able format (e.g. using `dput`). Also include the expected output for the sample data you give. It will make it a lot easier for SO respondents to provide help.

Comment: Is it really necessary for `smalldata` to have 25 (!) columns? In your example you seem to deal with only 3 columns.

Comment: thats just for example sake, my classification will be using most of the column. I just wanted to give brief idea about the problem i am facing. @MauritsEvers

Comment: Well, when you assign "Threat", all the other rows that don't match will be set to `NA`. Did you want them to have some other value?

Comment: I tried with multiple values, I even tried to match the condition with the values provided in the dataset. The problem is it ain't showing any errors which makes it more difficult to analyze the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to break it up in parts, then you can more easily spot yourself where the problem is.

That said, I can see one problem straightaway: your dates are stored as `character`.
Does it work if you do this?

```
as.POSIXct(DF$datetime, format='%m/%d/%y %H:%M') >= 
as.POSIXct("9/27/14 13:00", format='%m/%d/%y %H:%M')
```

Comment: I have already done that. I wanted to classify data from one datetime to other datetime eg. from '12/31/13 07:00' for daytime to '3/31/14 15:00' as spring. Note that I want to use multiple variables for classification including datetime. I converted the data from character to date time using the above code already.

Comment: Well, it's not in your example. But how about breaking it down?

Comment: What values did you expect to be set to 'Threat', and which part of your conditions fails? In your example. all dates are _after_ "9/27/14 16:00", so no values get set.